# Pyspark groupBy with custom partitioner

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to apply some custom partitioning when working with a given DataFrame. I found that the RDD [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=groupby#pyspark.RDD.groupBy) provides me with the desired functionality. Now when I say

```
dataframe.rdd.groupBy(lambda row: row[1:3], numPartitions, partitioner)
```

I end up with a `PythonRDD` that has a tuple as a key and a `ResultIterator` as the value. What I want to do next is convert this back to a DataFrame since I want to use the [apply](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=apply#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.apply) function of `GroupedData`. I have attempted multiple things but have been unlucky so far.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd check out the query plan and see if you could get a very similar plan with `repartition` or `repartitionByRange` operators. After `GroupedData` you can only execute grouping operators and that's how you can convert it "back" to a DataFrame.

Comment: @Jacek The problem is that I need to do a `groupBy` because my ML model needs to work on a certain dataset. If I do that than I automatically get an "implicit" shuffle that makes my work with repartition and custom partitioning obsolete.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried? What version of spark are you using?

Comment: Is there any issue with using the existing `.toDF()` function? I tried reproducing the issue but it worked fine for me. Codebin for the same is here : https://www.codepile.net/pile/0pZkbDLk

Comment: Would it be an option to use a normal `groupBy` on the dataframe and then `repartition` afterwards?